# Chrome not correct work with AJAX to PHP-script,user include directive

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, include

I have a problem with working Ajax query (with JQuery lib) in Google Chrome (12.0.742.112).
In my server-side script (PHP) if I use "include" directive - FireBug in Chrome say about error -

> "parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

In other browsers (FF,IE,Opera) - work fine.
Sample code from client-side:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data : { fun : "getconfigurations" },
    url: "test.php",
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(data) { 
        // do something
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Sample code for test.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
include "test2.php";
$result = array();
$result[] = array(0 => 1, 1 => "fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff");
$result[] = array(0 => 1, 1 => "hhhhhh");
$result[] = array(0 => 1, 1 => "gggggg");
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

In this script I try to include some file (test2.php):

```
<?php
function fun1()
{
return 10;
}
?>
```

**If i comment "include", it's work fine, and also If I copy code from test2.php to test.php - it's work fine.
This problem only in Chrome.**

I will very happy if you can hepl me. Thanks.

Comment: If I load test.php - in browser I see JSON string (with and without include). Possible solution - instead "include" just use code inline, but this not good solution...

Comment: when you view in browser right click and view source, see if there is anything else lurking.

Comment: just tried this with the exact code you have posted here and there is no problem in Chrome 12.

The only way I can get it to error is to make the included file print some nonsense before the json is echoed out.

    <?php
    print "blah";
    function fun1()
    {
    return 10;
    }
    ?>

Comment: In source of page only JSON string exist, no other symbols.

Comment: well, as said, I have copied the code exactly as you have here and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

well just load test.php in a browser and it will show what will be output to your ajax call.  Something is being output which is not valid JSON, chrome is strict about this.

I suspect something is being output before the json_encode part

Comment: I've done this kind of thing lots and never had to use the header(), not saying it should or shouldnt be used just that I have never had to and had no problems without it.